# Calc 3, finding planes that are parallel and perpendicular.

Tags: calculus, vectors

So I really need help with figuring out how to do this problem. I answered two of the questions (not sure if I am right) and I am just stuck on the 2nd part.

**Questions:
Two planes are given by the equations
Q:2x+y−3z=2 and R:−x+2y−z=1.**

**Question 1:
Find a vector normal to the plane Q. Find an equation of the plane which is parallel to Q and passes through the point (1,2,−1).**

Attempted answer: :

A vector normal to plane:
<2,1,-3>

A normal vector for new plane is <2,1,-3>. A pt on plane is <1,2,-3>

T/f equation is

2(x-1) + 1(y-2) - 3(z+1) = 0

= (2x-2) + (y-2) - (3z+3) = 0

**Question 2:
Find a vector normal to the plane R. Find a vector equation of the line that is perpendicular to the plane R and passes through the point (0,0,−1).**

Attempted Answer: Don't know how to start this one and help on how to start would be appreciated.

**Question 3:
Find a vector equation of the line in the intersection of Q and R.**

Attempted answer:

- i j k
- 2 1 -3
- -1 2 -1

6i+5j+5k = 9.27

Comment: For question 2, think about what “normal” means.

Answer (score 3):

You have done question 1 correctly.

Question 2 asks for a line normal to $R$ and passing through $(0,0,-1)$.

Thus your equation is $$ r =(0,0,-1)+t(-1,2,-1) $$

Question 3 requires either two points on the intersection or one point on the intersection and the direction vector which is found by cross product of normals to the planes.